# Why is my text messed up when converting a PDF to SVG?

Tags: vector, pdf, svg

I'm trying to convert a PDF to a vector image so that I can display it online.
When I convert it to SVG, it doesn't convert the font glyphs correctly.
When I convert to SWF, it is perfect, but I would rather use SVG.

### SVG Rendering ([download link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58922976/Sol_10.svg)):

[image: screenshot of SVG rendering]
<sup>[Click image for full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41qMG.png)</sup>

### PDF Rendering ([download link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58922976/Sol-10.1.pdf)):

[image: screenshot of PDF rendering]
<sup>[Click image for full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjQsK.png)</sup>

**What is going on? Is SWF superior to SVG or is this because of a bad converter?**

Comment: It's due to several embedded subset fonts in the PDF. You can't extract the vectors because its full of embedded subsets. Best you can do is parse it into a vector app, then fix the type and save as SVG.

Comment: There is a similar question here: [Embedding pdf in illustrator](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/18251/8708)

Answer (score 3):

### Why this is happening:

The PDF is embedding your font, the SVG is not. When I try and open the PDF in Illustrator, it yells at me for all the fonts I don't have installed:

```
The font CMBX10 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMEX10 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMMI10 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMMI8 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMR10 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMR8 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMSY10 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMSY8 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMTI10 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font MSBM10 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
```

Your SVG will just tell the rendering agent to grab whatever font is convenient, and in this case it makes your rendered output look crummy.

### How you can fix it:

#### Option 1: Embed all those fonts in the SVG

Rather than explain how to do this, just go check the answer to this question: [How do I embed Google Web Fonts into an SVG?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/5167/8708)

#### Option 2: Outline all the text

Assuming you're using Inkscape (since the SVG source code told me so), I believe all you'd have to do is select the text objects then use **Path** → ***Object to Path***

This will make the file size *considerably* larger. I'd try Option 1 before this. Also, the text will no longer be editable.